# Postfix: Recipient address rejected from another domain zones

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have successfully installed Postfix/Dovecot with virtual domains and TLS support like this article describes -
https://geekpeek.net/postfix-with-dovecot/ ...

But faced with the problem. I can send emails only to people in my domain zone (`blabla`, as example). It means that I can send email from `admin@blabla.com` to `info@blabla.com`. But when I'm trying to send email from my google account to this addresses I get next errors:

```
postfix/smtpd[19211]: connect from mail-wi0-f172.google.com[209.85.212.172]
Sep 10 18:23:17 amazon-ws.fs.local postfix/smtpd[19211]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wi0-f172.google.com[209.85.212.172]: 554 5.7.1 <info@blabla.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from=<{myaccount}@gmail.com> to=<info@blabla.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wi0-f172.google.com>
Sep 10 18:23:17 amazon-ws.fs.local postfix/smtpd[19211]: disconnect from mail-wi0-f172.google.com[209.85.212.172]
```

> Recipient address rejected: Access denied;

All i could understand is that my postfix server rejects this mail, but can't understand why. Postfix configuration (`main.cf`) attached below:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
default_process_limit = 100
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = amazon-ws.fs.local
mynetworks = 172.31.0.0/20, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
queue_minfree = 20971520
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 30
smtpd_recipient_limit = 1000
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/cert/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/cert/private/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/virtmailbox
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtdomains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtmail_maps
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

**Operating system:** RHEL7.1, Postfix Version 2.10.1

Where is the problem?

Comment: `smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks` probably permits your local mail to go through, though it's not clear from the posted configuration what `$mydomain` is or where `blabla.com` is set to be "local." The `mydestination` parameter may need attention?

Comment: When i configured postfix and added my virtual domain to `mydestination`, postfix daemon (log files) said that virtual domains don't need to be added to this srting. Only local domains and hostnames need to be included.
As i understood, virtual domains processed separate from `mydestination`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @alexkowalski mentioned, the problem that there was a short parameter (-o) in `master.cf` file **not in the `main.cf file**.

Because -o options in `master.cf` can override the options written in `main.cf` on a per-service basis, the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` param value were being taken from the `master.cf` file.

Notice the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` param :

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
------->  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

By commenting that line and every other -o line that I don't want, the values written in the `main.cf` file are the taken values.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, i found a problem! There was a short parameter  in `master.cf` file.

I had:

```
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

**Must be:**

```
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

Parameter `reject` needs to be changed to `reject_unauth_destination` because of smtpd rejects all incoming connections before sasl authentification begins.